# How to implement a 1-hour cooldown in a Discord hack command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a command that costs a lot memory usage, so I want to implement a 1-hour cooldown. I have used this, but it isn't working:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    
    run: async(client, message, args) => {


        const cooldown = new Set();

        if(cooldown.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.reply('Please Wait For 1 hour')
        } else {
            message.channel.send('text')
        cooldown.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            cooldown.delete(message.author.id)
        }, 3600000)}
        
    }
}
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: I would use some kind of cron job

Comment: We need more detail beyond "it isn't working". Do you get an error message? Does it delay for some incorrect amount of time? No delay at all? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, a new set is created at each run, so it will always be empty.
You should make your cooldown set in a global scope. Try to instantiate the set before the module.export